# Linux Ubuntu how to get remote hostname

Tags: c, linux, python-3.x, python-2.7

How do you get the hostname of the one who is connected to the same network as i am.
Example i am at 192.168.1.16
other is at 192.168.1.15

how do i get to know his hostname with python or any command that would help?

Comment: Your tagging is pretty bad and it's hard to tell whether this is even a programming question, or a system usage/administration question....

Comment: You should check out this Ubuntu Doc page [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/205063/command-to-get-the-hostname-of-remote-server-using-ip-address)

Comment: In bash you could try `w`. `man w`. ("show who is logged in and what they are doing")

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

`nslookup IP_ADDRESS`

It should show you a field `name` that contain the hostname.

There's also a specific command, but I don't know if it's included in every distributions:

`resolveip IP_ADDRESS`

Give it a try. It also has a `-s` option that gives you the hostname and nothing else, very useful if you need to retrieve it and store it in a variable.

`resolveip -s IP_ADDRESS`